# How to see all TriggeredEvents for control

Tags: c#, wpf, events, .net-4.0, triggers

Anyway to view all the events triggered specifically for a ui control.

I have integrated WPF toolkit extended into my application and currently facing an issue where the TimePicker does not trigger the ValueChanged unless it loses focus. that would be understandable but it has buttons in the control that changes the value ... so losing focus is not ideal as I would require to click on another control.

This is the first time I get this type of issue but there is a lot of times where I am not too positive which event I want to use so I just put a bunch of events with breakpoints and see which one gets hit with the ideal moment.

For that reason, I am curious to know if there is any sort of debugger tool or something similar that can register/show all the events being hit without me putting a breakpoint in every event or modifying the controls code ?

Comment: While it might be possible, it would be pretty hard.  [I asked a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865848/general-purpose-fromevent-method) about dynamically adding an event handler to an event when you don't know the delegate signature at compile time.  See for yourself the complexity that's involved in the answer.  You'd need to do something that's only slightly less complex to create a handler that just printed the event info somewhere and then do that for each event.

Answer (score 0):

If ValueChanged is a RoutedEvent you could use a tool like snoop. http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

the events tab will show you events as they are triggered (note that you'll have to check off the event that you want to listen to in the dropdown.