# callback based async method with multiple parameters to awaitabletask

Tags: c#, asynchronous, callback, myob

I have the following code to connect to MYOB's SDK

```
    var cfsCloud = new CompanyFileService(_configurationCloud, null, _oAuthKeyService);
    cfsCloud.GetRange(OnComplete, OnError);
```

where

```
private  void OnComplete(HttpStatusCode statusCode, CompanyFile[] companyFiles)
    {  // ask for credentials etc }
```

I want to convert this to use a TaskCompletionSource
like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645973/how-to-make-an-old-style-async-method-awaitable)

however my OnComplete has multiple parameters.
How do I code that?

Comment: The [SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MYOB.AccountRight.API.SDK/) for Accountright API supports async/await i.e. [GetRangeAsync](https://github.com/MYOB-Technology/AccountRight_Live_API_.Net_SDK/blob/master/MYOB.API.SDK/SDK/Services/CompanyFileService.cs#L53)

Comment: Augh! I have tripped up on that before. Care to put it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment

The [SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MYOB.AccountRight.API.SDK/) for Accountright API supports async/await i.e. [GetRangeAsync](https://github.com/MYOB-Technology/AccountRight_Live_API_.Net_SDK/blob/master/MYOB.API.SDK/SDK/Services/CompanyFileService.cs#L53)

so you can do something like this if you wanted/needed to [wrap it in a TaskCompletionSource](http://www.levibotelho.com/development/async-processes-with-taskcompletionsource/)

```
static Task<CompanyFile[]> DoWork()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<CompanyFile[]>();
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var cfsCloud = new CompanyFileService(_configurationCloud, null, _oAuthKeyService);
        var files = await cfsCloud.GetRangeAsync();
        tcs.SetResult(files);
    });
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: except the CompanyFileService parameters need to be added as parameters to DoWork because the method is static.

Comment: @kirsteng - you can easily remove the `static`

Comment: Shaun and @kirsteng, if you wrap it like this, you should also handle exceptions inside this async lambda and use `TCS.SetException`. Otherwise they may go lost.

Comment: @Noseratio - you are right but this was just an example to point him in the right direction