# MYOB oauthService.GetTokensAsync not showing dialog

Tags: c#, oauth, async-await, myob, taskcompletionsource

As a result of my question [about TaskCompletionSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341172/callback-based-async-method-with-multiple-parameters-to-awaitabletask)

I tried a similar technique for getting the tokens

```
private t.Task<OAuthTokens> GetOAuthTokens()
    {
        var tcs = new t.TaskCompletionSource<OAuthTokens>();
        t.Task.Run(
            async () =>
            {
                var oauthService = new OAuthService(_configurationCloud);
                var code = OAuthLogin.GetAuthorizationCode(_configurationCloud);
                var response = await oauthService.GetTokensAsync(code);

                tcs.SetResult(response);
            });
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

calling this using

```
var task1 = GetOAuthTokens();
_oAuthKeyService.OAuthResponse = task1.Result;
```

However the program locks up when I run it.

The following works OK

```
        var oauthService = new OAuthService(_configurationCloud);
        var code = OAuthLogin.GetAuthorizationCode(_configurationCloud);  // causes a login dialog
        var tokens = oauthService.GetTokens(code);
        _oAuthKeyService.OAuthResponse = tokens;
```

and brings up the authorisation dialog box.

Comment: @shaun_a_wilde  please can you help?

Comment: What UI? if it's message pump based like WinForms or WPF it's expected to block. Why are you using `Task.Run` and `TaskCompletionSource` to call already asynchronous code?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify that it is the program that locks up rather than the UI. ( I have to Ctrl Alt Delete to end the program ). I am using Task.Run and TaskCompletionSource so as to wait for the task to run.  There is a synchronous option .GetTokens, but I am experimenting.

Comment: Can you show the calling code? Is it an event handler?

Comment: I included it in the question under "calling this using"

Comment: What's the method signature of the calling code? Is it an event handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I answered your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341172/callback-based-async-method-with-multiple-parameters-to-awaitabletask) I assumed you had a requirement to use a TaskCompletionSource object so I am sorry if this has sent you in the wrong direction. As [Paulo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402366/paulo-morgado) has said you don't normally need to use TaskCompletionSource with async/await code but you do need to understand a bit more how to use it.

Calling [Result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) on a Task will cause that thread to block, now in a non-UI thread this isn't such an issue (just not ideal) but in a UI thread this will effectively stop your [UI from responding](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) until the task has completed, assuming it just doesn't stop completely due to a deadlock.

The thing is to learn how to use async/await in a UI environment because to get it to work you have too use async/await everywhere otherwise you will end up trying to use Task.Result to access your data and get a blocked UI thread for your troubles.

This is a good starter guide - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Now I assume you are pulling the `code` from the page like this (cobbled from [code samples](https://github.com/MYOB-Technology/AccountRight_WindowsMobile_sampleApp/blob/master/myob.sample/MainPage.xaml.cs#L90) on GitHub) and then fetching the tokens.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var content = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
    var regex = new Regex(@"\<title\>(.+?)=(.+?)\</title\>");
    var match = regex.Match(content);
    if (!match.Success || match.Groups.Count != 3)
        return;

    switch (match.Groups[1].Value.ToLowerInvariant())
    {
        case "code": // we have a code
            var code = match.Groups[2].Value;
            var config = new ApiConfiguration(Configuration.ClientId, Configuration.ClientSecret, Configuration.RedirectUrl);
            var service = new OAuthService(config, new WebRequestFactory(config));
            var tokens = service.GetTokensAsync(code).Result; // <= blocking
            _keyService.OAuthResponse = tokens;
            break;

        case "error": // user probably said "no thanks"
            webBrowser1.Navigate(_logoffUri);
            break;
    }
}
```

however your code is blocking on the `.Result`

What you need to do is use async/await all the way up however when you use await it complains about the lack of async on the method, so, just add it; yes this is allowed and there are many articles and blog posts about this that [catch people new to async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28601678/calling-async-method-on-button-click) in winforms/wpf UI.

e.g.

```
// we add async to the callback - yup it's allowed 
private async void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var content = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
    var regex = new Regex(@"\<title\>(.+?)=(.+?)\</title\>");
    var match = regex.Match(content);
    if (!match.Success || match.Groups.Count != 3)
        return;

    switch (match.Groups[1].Value.ToLowerInvariant())
    {
        case "code": // we have a code
            var code = match.Groups[2].Value;
            var config = new ApiConfiguration(Configuration.ClientId, Configuration.ClientSecret, Configuration.RedirectUrl);
            var service = new OAuthService(config, new WebRequestFactory(config));
            var tokens = await service.GetTokensAsync(code); // <= now we can use await here => non-blocking
            _keyService.OAuthResponse = tokens;
            break;

        case "error": // user probably said "no thanks"
            webBrowser1.Navigate(_logoffUri);
            break;
    }
}
```

I've [uploaded the code as gist](https://gist.github.com/sawilde/247533057916bcafb6d5) I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Shaun.

I get that the following blocks:   
var tokens = service.GetTokensAsync(code).Result;

I get that I can use service.GetTokens() instead,      which will also block.

What I dont understand is why the login dialog only appears when I use service.GetTokens().  When I use the Async option the program locks up and never unlocks.  It is as though the login dialog is invisible.

Comment: @kirsteng - with the small snippets supplied it is hard to tell - GetTokens implementation is [available](https://github.com/MYOB-Technology/AccountRight_Live_API_.Net_SDK/blob/master/MYOB.API.SDK/SDK/Services/OAuthService.cs#L64) on github actually uses an alternative asynchronous approach that does not rely on the async/await pattern - so it can be used with versions of the framework that do not have async/await e.g. .NET2.

Comment: Thanks Shaun, I am just going to use the non asynchronous version of GetTokens() for the moment.