# Pass templated method as an object to reflection created method.invoke

Tags: c#, templates, dynamic, reflection, delegates

I have a function declared along the lines of:

```
public delegate void Callback<T>(T arg1) where T : EventT;
public void RegisterCallback<T>(Callback<T> callback) where T : EventT
```

I want to call this via reflection as the type in a particular instance isn't know to me at runtime, I'm trying

```
Type classType = Type.GetType (eventNameString);
MethodInfo baseMethod = eventDispatcher.GetType ().GetMethod ("RegisterCallback");
MethodInfo typedMethod = baseMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] {classType});
```

Which if I understand it correctly is now making a method to except this dynamic type, however my concern is how to pass the Callback parameter into the method invoke

```
typedMethod.Invoke (eventDispatcher, new object[] { ??? });
```

I'm not sure how I can declare a delegate to pass into the object[] params that will also be typed agaisnt classType, I'm fairly new to Csharp as well so am a little lost,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you have functionally the same problem described in [this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865848/general-purpose-fromevent-method).

Answer (score 0):

simply pass your instance of you delegate

```
static void myglobalcallback(object arg)
{
    //....
}

var dmethod = new DynamicMethod(string.Empty, typeof(void), new Type[] { thegenerictype }, true);
var body = dmethod.GetILGenerator();
body.Emit(opcodes.ldarg_0);
body.Emit(opcodes.castclass, typeof(object));
body.emit(opcodes.call, typeof(mycurrenttype).getmethod("myglobalcallback"));
body.emit(opcodes.ret);
var delegate = dmethod.createdelegate(tyepof(Callbacl<>).MakegenericType(thegenericType));
new object[] { mydelegate }
```

Comment: He's asking how to create a delegate based on that type.

Comment: Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Callback<>).makegenerictype(...), mymethodinfo)

Comment: That's assuming he has a method that is of the appropriate signature.

Comment: if he want call a delegate without the generic type defined, he can create a dynamic method with the good signature calling his method and create a delegate via dynamicmethod.createdelegate and simply pass it.

Comment: And how should he go about creating a dynamic method of a signature not known at compile time?

Comment: dynamicmethod id define at runtime. new dynamicmethod(string.empty, tyeof(void), new Type[] { thegenerictargettype });

Comment: Which of course requires providing the implementation of that method in IL.  Not something that a brand new C# developer is likely to be able to do.

Comment: just provide a minimal implementation.. call another method wich take object as parameter. void mycallback(object arg); in ilgenerator => emit(castclass, typeof(object)); emit(opcodes.call, mycallbackmethodinfo)

Comment: The point remains that your answer has provided only a tiny bit of the solution, much of which is quite non-trivial.  Your answer should actually be explaining how to do all of those things for it to actually answer the question.