# Wait for an Event - Better solution than polling?

Tags: c#, events, wait

I'm working on a Problem on an existing Project. We want to read an ADC-value and normally we use there a fire-and-forget concept. We ask for the value and after the value is read an event is raised. However now I have to implement a function, which returns a value directly. My idea was to solve this Problem with polling.

```
public class Information
{
    public delegate void NewADCValueArrived(double newValue);

    private event NewADCValueArrived newAdcValue;

    private double getADCValueDirectly()
    {
        double value = -1;

        NewADCValueArrived handler = delegate(double newValue)
        {
                value = newValue;
        };
        newAdcValue += handler;

        askFornewValues(); //Fire and forget

        timeout = 0;
        while(value != -1 && timeout <100)
        {
            timeout++;
            Thread.sleep(1); //Want to avoid this!! because sleeping for 1 ms is very inaccurate
        }

        newAdcValue -= handler;

        if (value != -1)
        {
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            throw Exception("Timeout");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem now is, that I want to avoid polling. Because often the response is even faster than 1 ms and I want to finish the function as fast as possible. **Do you have a better idea to solve this Problem?**

In the c#-Documentation I found some information about WaitHandlers but I was not able to integrate them into my program. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TaskCompletionSource` to abstract the event as a `Task`. You can refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865848/general-purpose-fromevent-method) for how to do that. You don't even need to refer the answers; question itself shows how.

Once you get the `Task` you don't have to poll anymore. You can do all sort of interesting things like `Wait`, `ContinueWith` or even `await`.

For the timeout you can use call `TaskCompletionSource.SetCanceled` with a `Timer`.

*As to how to unsubscribe from the event:(asked in comments)*

```
public class MyClass
{
    public event Action OnCompletion;
}

public static Task FromEvent(MyClass obj)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    Action completion = null;
    completion = () =>
    {
        tcs.SetResult(null);

        obj.OnCompletion -= completion;
    };

    obj.OnCompletion += completion;

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Thanks your solution seems pretty good. One Question to the linked page: every time I call the FromEvent() function there is added a new function to the event. Do I have to remove this afterwards or is the Garbage-collector doing this for me. In my case this function could be called very often.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the option I would probably go with a task based solution.

Otherwise, what you can do is set up an AutoResetEvent and wait for that to be triggered by the event handler.

```
private double getADCValueDirectly()
{
    double value = -1;
    AutoResetEvent eventCompleted = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    NewADCValueArrived handler = delegate(double newValue)
    {
        value = newValue;
        // signal the waithandle
        eventCompleted.Set();
    };
    newAdcValue += handler;

    askFornewValues(); //Fire and forget
    eventCompleted.WaitOne(); // optionally enter a timeout here

    newAdcValue -= handler;

    if (value != -1)
    {
        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        throw Exception("Timeout");
    }
}
```

There's an excellent tutorial on C# thread handling at http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_AutoResetEvent

Answer (score 0):

If its really **realtime** and you can't afford to let the Dispatcher take action, you could just do a *busy wait*:

```
    timeout = 0;
    while(value != -1 && timeout <100000)
    {
        timeout++;
        for(int j= 0; j < 100; j++); // keep CPU busy
    }
```

This assumes that your `value` is modified by another thread and that you allow the program to freeze for a short period of time. On the plus side no windows dispatching (Task, Events, etc) crosses your way.

Comment: `100000 * 100` iterations for busy wait? You're probably planning to burn the cpu just for the sake of waiting?

Comment: On a 1Ghz CPU this will take 100k * 100 = 10M cycles == 100ms (the actual numbers needed will vary...)

Comment: Use the built-in implementation of [SpinWait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/spinwait) instead. Do not reinvent the wheel, especially not with such hard-coded values.