# Task await does not return the result

Tags: c#, async-await, task, deadlock

I am trying to write a function which uses Task and TaskCompletion.

My problem is that after login, the result is not returned. I used similar code before and it was working. I do not know what causes for this situation.

```
public async Task<byte[]> Sign(byte[] documentContent)
{
    var service = new SignServiceWrapper("https://example.com?wsdl");
    var loginResult = await Task.Run(() => service.Login(loginRequest));

    //....
}
```

and my SignServiceWrapper class

```
public class SignServiceWrapper
{
    private static string _webServiceUrl;
    private  BrokerClientClient client;

    public SignServiceWrapper(string webServiceUrl)
    {
        _webServiceUrl = webServiceUrl;
    }

    public Task<loginResponse> Login(loginRequest request)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<loginResponse>();

        ClientGenerator.WebServiceUrl = _webServiceUrl;

        ClientGenerator.InitializeService(); 
        client = ClientGenerator.ServiceClient;   

        client.loginCompleted += (sender, loginResult) =>
        {
            if (loginResult.Error != null)
                tcs.SetException(loginResult.Error);
            else
                tcs.TrySetResult(loginResult.Result);
        };    

        client.loginAsync(request);                

        return tcs.Task;
    }

    // ...
}
```

If I call my login function like that it works

```
var loginResult = Task.Run(() => service.Login(loginRequest));
loginResult.Wait();
```

I know that there is kind of a deadlock but I don't know how to solve this here and which object.

Comment: How long have you waited for the task to complete? Have you tried stepping through the task to make sure it is processing?

Comment: I put a breakpoint in loginCompleted event and the result comes there but problem is it does not return

Comment: `await` isn't broken. Your code though is rather unusual - Task.Run *and* TCS *and* web service calls, that already has a `loginAsync` method? Why don't you remove the *entire* `Login` method and just call `var response=await client.loginAsync(request);` ?

Comment: Note that using `Task.Run` and then making a blocking call inside it results in fake asynchrony. WCF's asynchronous methods *don't use threads at all*. Windows IO is actually asynchronous at the kernel level with blocking simulated to make programming easier. Using `Task.Run` on top of a blocking method wastes a background thread. Using the WCF proxy's Async or Begin/End methods doesn't

Comment: I generate a proxy class from webservice and it contains only async calls like that. your code that you give, loginAsync is a void method, it does not return anything so i have to use loginCompleted event to get result..  so for that i have to use TaskCompletion

Comment: Post your code then. Why *don't* you use WCF's proxies? WCF generates asynchronous methods already - Task-based since 2013, Begin/Async earlier. ASMX services also generate Begin/End methods, probably Task-based too. It looks like your code is trying to reverse whatever the proxy is doing and get back to the original asynchronous methods

Comment: Well I used silverlight util tool to create proxy from the webservice (i do not want to add the service as a service reference) maybe i should do like that

Comment: What is the implementation of the `LoginClient.login` service, I want to see how it's `login` method is implemented.

Comment: Please tell us **exactly** what you mean by "is not returned". Are you saying that it does not return, at all, period? Or that it does return but returns the wrong value? In other words, is the problem a deadlock/lost-in-space task, or wrong return value?

Comment: @DavidPine, I cant show, because i dont have the webservice's code.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, It means             var loginResult = Task.Run(() => service.Login(loginRequest)).Result;
after this method, the program does not cycle, it waits there even the completed event is triggered..

Comment: So for now I use the code like that and it works var loginResult = Task.Run(() => service.Login(loginRequest)).Result

Comment: So you have a deadlock or are losing tasks.

Comment: Yes I have a deadlock but i dont know because of which object. When I use Wait function instead of await it works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working [<kbd>.NET Fiddle</kbd>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ItZ6u9).

I think your `.Login` method is trying to do too much. The first thing that I noticed (and can only imagine how it's implemented) is the static `ClientGenerator`, that has *static mutable state*. This which is alarming and a very specific code smell. I would love to see what the client itself looks like and how that is implemented as that would certainly help to better answer this question.

Based on what you shared thus far (and assuming that the `client.loginAsync` returns a `Task<loginResponse>`), I would say that you could do the following:

```
public class SignServiceWrapper
{
    private static string _webServiceUrl;
    private  BrokerClientClient client;

    public SignServiceWrapper(string webServiceUrl)
    {
        _webServiceUrl = webServiceUrl;
    }

    public Task<loginResponse> LoginAsync(loginRequest request)
    {
        ClientGenerator.WebServiceUrl = _webServiceUrl;
        ClientGenerator.InitializeService();
        client = ClientGenerator.ServiceClient;

        return client.loginAsync(request);
    }

    // ...
}
```

You could then consume this as such:

```
public async Task<byte[]> Sign(byte[] documentContent)
{
    var service = new SignServiceWrapper("https://example.com?wsdl");
    var loginResult = await service.LoginAsync(loginRequest);

    //...
}
```

If the `client.loginAsync` doesn't return what you're looking for, then you'll need to approach this doing [something similar to your current approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12867906/2410379). Or if you are locked in to the [event-based async pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7a34yad(v=vs.110).aspx), you have other considerations - like whether or not you want to support cancellation, `IsBusy`, progress, incremental results and if you have the ability to have the event args inherit the `System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs`, etc...

One final consideration, if the `client.loginAsync` is `Task` returning, even if it doesn't return the `loginResponse` you need to await it like so:

```
public async Task<loginResponse> Login(loginRequest request)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<loginResponse>();

    ClientGenerator.WebServiceUrl = _webServiceUrl;
    ClientGenerator.InitializeService();
    client = ClientGenerator.ServiceClient;
    client.loginCompleted += (sender, loginResult) =>
    {
        if (loginResult.Error != null)
            tcs.SetException(loginResult.Error);
        else
            tcs.TrySetResult(loginResult.Result);
    };    

    await client.loginAsync(request);                

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

**Update**

After discussion with OP this [<kbd>.NET Fiddle</kbd>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/epRVLM) seemed to align with his needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but loginAsync method is a void method so await does not work! Well I solved the problem by using like           var loginResult = Task.Run(() => service.Login(loginRequest)).Result;

Comment: That is not solving the problem, but rather setting yourself up for another deadlock situation. Do you have control over the `.loginAsync` and that client class?

Comment: Yes I know that its not a proper solution :) The loginAsync is a webservice function and i cant access the webservice, because its not our project, then is a external source.

Comment: And I do not want to write event based things :) I was looking for solving the problem with different way..

Comment: Did you see my `.NET Fiddle`, that is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: Yes I see it, but i dont want to use an eventhandler because the log has already its own completed event. And Login is not only method in this service and i have to write all methods for my service wrapper..

Comment: You are already using an event-handler. If you are taking a dependency on this service, and you are wrapping it... that is what you need to do. You could always encapsulate the logic for the various events in your wrapper such that all the calls you need to wrap are delegated down to a single entry point. This would make your code much more SOLID.

Comment: you think that my approach is not good? I mean if i use something like that var loginResult = Task.Run(() => service.Login(loginRequest)).Result; or loginResult.Wait(); instead of await keyword? Do I have to use an eventhandler what you wrote?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133459/discussion-between-david-pine-and-ertan2002).

Answer (score -1):

Change `var loginResult =   await Task.Run(() =>service.Login(loginRequest));`
To `var loginResult =   await service.Login(loginRequest);`

Comment: That probably isn't enough since the `Login` method also mixes up asynchronous and non-asynchronous methods. Notice the TCS *and* the `loginAsync` method. The problem could in `ClientGenerator`